# TCP send/retrieve headers by bytes

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have the client configuration:

```
<beans:bean id="itemSerializerDeserializer"
    class="org.mbracero.integration.ItemSerializerDeserializer" />

<beans:bean id="resultSerializerDeserializer"
    class="org.mbracero.integration.ResultSerializerDeserializer" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="clientRequestData"
    type="client" host="${clientRequestData.host}" port="${clientRequestData.port}" single-use="true"
    serializer="itemSerializerDeserializer" deserializer="resultSerializerDeserializer" />

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="requestDataOutGateway"
    request-channel="requestData" connection-factory="clientRequestData"
    request-timeout="10000" reply-timeout="10000" remote-timeout="10000" />
```

SimpleGateway:

```
public interface SimpleGateway {
     @Gateway(requestChannel="requestData")
     Result sendData(Item item);
}
```

And the server configuration:

```
<int:channel id="channelServerRequestData" />
<int:channel id="channelServerResponseData" />

<beans:bean id="requestService" class="org.mbracero.integration.RequestService" />

<beans:bean id="itemSerializerDeserializer"
    class="org.mbracero.integration.ItemSerializerDeserializer" />

<beans:bean id="resultSerializerDeserializer"
    class="org.mbracero.integration.ResultSerializerDeserializer" />

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="requestDataServer"
    type="server" port="${requestDataServer.port}" single-use="true" deserializer="itemSerializerDeserializer"
    serializer="resultSerializerDeserializer" />

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="TCPInboundGateway"
    connection-factory="requestDataServer" request-channel="channelServerRequestData"
    reply-channel="channelServerResponseData" error-channel="errorChannel" />
```

RequestService:

```
@Service
public class RequestService {
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="channelServerRequestData", outputChannel="channelServerResponseData")
public Result requestData(Item input) {
    System.out.println("Input :::: " + input);
    Result ret = new Result("AAA", "DDDD");
    System.out.println("Ret :::: " + ret);
    return ret;
  }
}
```

ItemSerializerDeserializer:

```
public class ItemSerializerDeserializer implements Serializer<Item>, Deserializer<Item> {
(...)
}
```

ResultSerializerDeserializer:

```
public class ResultSerializerDeserializer implements Serializer<Result>, Deserializer<Result> {
(...)
}
```

Now I have to add some headers (send & retrieve), but I need do it like custom serializers/deserializers I write above.

For example, I need send the next headers:

- Issuer: 4 bytes. Initial position 1 - final position 4
- Client: 4 bytes. Ini pos 5 - final pos 8
- Product: 2 bytes. Ini pos 9 - final pos 10
- Type: 3 bytes. Ini pos 11 - final pos 13
- (...)

I have send and retrieve these headers by bytes and positions (no by name/value like Map).

With my custom serializers/deserializers I have this work with the payload but I don't know how do it with headers.

I have read something about the attribute mapper but I don't know if I'm in the right way.

In client config something like:

```
(...)
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="clientRequestData"
    type="client" host="${clientRequestData.host}" port="${clientRequestData.port}" single-use="true"
    serializer="itemSerializerDeserializer" deserializer="resultSerializerDeserializer"
    mapper="mapper" />

<beans:bean id="mapper"
      class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.MessageConvertingTcpMessageMapper">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="messageConverter">
        <beans:bean class="??????????"/>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
(...)
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `MessageConvertingTcpMessageMapper` with a `MapMessageConverter`.

The general idea is for, outbound, the converter converts the `Message` to a `Map` containing all the `headers` and `payload` and the serializer serializes the map to a `byte[]`. You can tell the `MapMessageConverter` which headers you want included in the map so you can access them in the serializer.

On the inbound side, the deserializer creates a `Map` from the `byte[]` and then the `MessageConverter.toMessage()` converts the map to a `Message`.

See the [MapJsonSerializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/serializer/MapJsonSerializer.java#L49) for an example.

Also see [this test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/763/files#diff-fdfde16ba252092c0d59e9b956096ba1).

**EDIT**

Here's a naive implementation (no error checking or length checks on output)...

```
private volatile Deserializer<byte[]> packetDeserializer = new ByteArrayLfSerializer();

private volatile Serializer<byte[]> packetSerializer = new ByteArrayLfSerializer();


@Override
public Map<?, ?> deserialize(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = readToEndOfMessage(inputStream);
    String asString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("issuer", asString.substring(0, 5));
    headers.put("client", asString.substring(4, 9));
    headers.put("product", asString.substring(9, 11));
    headers.put("type", asString.substring(11, 14));
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("headers", headers);
    map.put("payload", createPayloadFromRemainingBytes(bytes));
    return map;
}

@Override
public void serialize(Map<?, ?> object, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> headers = (Map<String, String>) object.get("headers");
    outputStream.write(headers.get("issuer").getBytes("UTF-8"));
    outputStream.write(headers.get("client").getBytes("UTF-8"));
    outputStream.write(headers.get("product").getBytes("UTF-8"));
    outputStream.write(headers.get("type").getBytes("UTF-8"));
    outputStream.write(convertPayloadToBytes(object.get("payload")));
}
```

Used together with a `MapMessageConverter`, the Spring Integration headers will be conveyed to the other side along with the data and he will decode the data and create an inbound message with those headers.

Comment: `(...)the converter converts the Message to a Map containing all the headers and payload and the serializer serializes the map to a byte[].`
<br/>
Can I differenciate in serialize the header of the payload?
I need retrieve (and send) the header and the payload independently, for example, can I do this?:
Header:  Issuer: 4 bytes. Initial position 1 - final position 4
Client: 4 bytes. Ini pos 5 - final pos 8
(...)
Payload: Name: 3 bytes. Initial position 1 - final position 3
Email: 4 bytes. Ini pos 4 - final pos 7
(...)
The header and payload start in byte 1,payload not continue after header

Comment: No; you have to send everything as a single message; it shouldn't make any difference whether it's sent in 1 or 2 writes since you control both ends of the communication. If you need a delimiter between the headers and payload, just add one. TCP is just a stream after all and all we're doing is add some structure so both ends can talk to each other.

Comment: Ok, but TCP [distinguishes between data and header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure). I thought there was a link between this and the couple payload/header.

So when you send the message content differences between payload & header?

For example, the following lines are displayed in the log to show both what is sent as it is received.

(........)

Comment: (..............)`DEBUG o.s.i.i.t.c.TcpNetConnection - Message sent GenericMessage [payload=Item [id=3, name=Hecho con spring integration], headers={timestamp=1436219114637, id=917e9286-de6d-8bb2-8bed-8ad40495c85d, errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2e8f2669, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2e8f2669}]`
(...)
`DEBUG o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Response GenericMessage [payload=Result [code=AAA, description=DDDD], headers={timestamp=1436219114640, id=ac2...........}]`

Comment: That's at an extremely low level. At the application level it's just a stream of bytes. Headers in this context are application layer headers, not network layer headers. Application data (including headers) are conveyed in the data part of a TCP packet. ...... Please don't post stuff like that in comments; it's unreadable; edit your question instead.

Comment: For example, an external system wants to send a message header and differentiated data (for example, as in the example above I explained), it would be possible to capture this information through spring integration? And how?

Thank you very much and sorry for the insistence (trying to understand and make up my mind about spring integration)

Comment: As I said, at the application layer it's just a stream of bytes, you can apply whatever semantics you want; Spring Integration provides all the hooks you need (mappers and serializers) to allow you to format the data in any way you want. Trust me, you don't want to get into the bowels of the TCP stack. It sounds like you are very close to what you need but are having trouble connecting the final dots.